# Determining number of cache misses for in-place reversal of an array, on a 2-way associative cache

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Consider a 32-bit computer. With 2-way associative cache, cache blocks are 8 words each and has 512 sets.
Consider the following code block

```
int A[N];
for(int i =0;i<N/2;i++){
int tmp = A[i];
A[i] = A[N-i-1];
A[N-i-1] = tmp;
}
```

Assume N is a multiple of 8. Determine a formula for the number of cache misses, with variable N.

**My research :** 
Each block in memory will have 8 words (1 words = 32 bit = 4 bytes)
A block # b will map to b mod 512
There are 512 sets. Where each set has two lines in cache and each line is a block.
So things will be transferred block wise from memory to cache.

Now as per my understanding memory will be organized in blocks of 8 words.
Suppose N = 8 * K
Since ints are 32 bits. IT will be like :
A[0], A[1], A[2],A[3],..A[7]
A[8],...................A[15]
.

A[8*(K-1)],...............A[N-1]
So this is how Array will be laid out in memory with K blocks.
And when there is a cache miss a complete line will be transferred into cache.
In the first iteration code will access A[0] and A[N-1]
So Line 0 and Line K-1 will be put into cache.
At second iteration it will access A[1] and A[N-2] and both of them are already in cache
Following this logic, There will be two cache misses for i=0.
None for i=1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Then for i = 8, code will access A[8] and A[N-9] again two cache misses.

for i = N/2-5 it will acess A[N/2-5] and A[N/2+4] these two will be in different blocks so again two 
cache misses.

Not sure if I am proceeding in the right direction. I need to come up with the formula of number of cache misses in terms of N.

Comment: Another simple way to thing about it could be : Each cache block = 8 words = 32 bytes. int = 4 bytes. So each cache block contains 8 ints. In total there are N ints. So there will be `N/8 cache misses`. This seems correct. But it doesn't take into acccount. The 2-way associative thing and 512 sets

Comment: `Cache size = 512 x 32 x2 =32 KB` , 
`index bits (set bits) = 9`, 
`offset bits = 5 bits`